# Adding parent ID information to properties in a hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I need to grab all of the ID values from the previous object and build out an array of the IDs in each parent item. This needs to be done in a generic manner and cannot use the name of the property. However, each property does inherit a base class. There may be other arrays on the structure that do not inherit from the `SubResource` class, so only those that do, should be added to the identifierHierarchy.

```
export abstract class SubResource {
  public id: number;
  public identifierHierarchy: number[] = [];
}
```

Given the following snippet of data

```
let data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Deer, spotted",
  "parents": [
    {
      "id": "133",
      "name": "Jaime Coldrick",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "0723",
          "name": "Ardys Kurten",
          "grandchildren": [
            {
              "id": "384",
              "name": "Madelle Bauman"
            },
            {
              "id": "0576",
              "name": "Pincas Maas"
            },
            {
              "id": "5",
              "name": "Corrie Beacock"
            }
          ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I need for the values on the objects to now be.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Deer, spotted",
    "parents": [{
        "id": "133",
        "name": "Jaime Coldrick",
        "identifierHierarchy": ["1"],
        "children": [{
            "id": "0723",
            "name": "Ardys Kurten",
            "identifierHierarchy": ["1", "133"],
            "grandchildren": [{
                    "id": "384",
                    "name": "Madelle Bauman",
                    "identifierHierarchy": ["1", "133", "0723"]
                },
                {
                    "id": "0576",
                    "name": "Pincas Maas",
                    "identifierHierarchy": ["1", "133", "0723"]
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Corrie Beacock",
                    "identifierHierarchy": ["1", "133", "0723"]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as type-safe as I would like, but...

```
export class RestHierarchyService {
  public static assignHierarchyIdentifiers(subResource: SubResource | any, parentIdentifiers: any): void {
    const composedSubResources = Object.entries(subResource)
      .filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'identifierHierarchy' && value.constructor === Array)
      .map(([key, value]) => Object.values(value).reduce(x => x));

    subResource.identifierHierarchy = parentIdentifiers;
    composedSubResources.forEach(x => RestHierarchyService.assignHierarchyIdentifiers(x, [...parentIdentifiers, subResource.id]));
  }
}
```

```
ancestry.forEach(x => x.parents.forEach(y => RestHierarchyService.assignHierarchyIdentifiers(y, [x.id])));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```js
function addHierarchy(items: any[], chain: string[], inherited: string[] = []) {
    items.forEach(item => {
        if (inherited.length)
            item.identifierHierarchy = inherited;
        if (chain.length)
            addHierarchy(item[chain[0]], chain.slice(1), [...inherited, item.id]);
    });
}

addHierarchy(data, ['parents', 'children', 'grandchildren']);
```